# Dynamic programming-memoization

Tags: java, dynamic, memoization

I am working on a DP problem in which a string of words with space removed, and I need to implement both buttom-up and memoization version to split the string into individual english words. However, I got the buttom-up version, however, the memoization seems a little complicated.

```
 /* Split a string into individual english words
 * @String str the str to be splitted
 * @Return a sequence of words separated by space if successful,
     null otherwise
 */
public static String buttom_up_split(String str){
    int len = str.length();
    int[] S = new int[len+1];
    /*Stores all the valid strings*/
    String[] result = new String[len+1];  
    /*Initialize the array*/
    for(int i=0; i <= len; i++){
        S[i] = -1;
    }
    S[0] =0;
    for(int i=0; i < len; i++){
        if(S[i] != -1){
            for(int j= i+1; j <= len; j++){
                String sub = str.substring(i, j);
                int k = j;      
                if(isValidEnglishWord(sub)){
                    S[k] = 1; //set true indicates a valid split
                    /*Add space between words*/
                    if(result[i] != null){ 
                        /*Add the substring to the existing words*/
                        result[i+ sub.length()] = result[i] + " " + sub;
                    }
                    else{
                        /*The first word*/
                        result[i+ sub.length()] = sub;
                    }
                }

            }
        }
    }
    return result[len];  //return the last element of the array
}
```

I really confused how to convert this buttom_up_version to the memoized version, hope someone can help..

Answer (score 1):

Well, I'm not an export of memoization, but the idea is to have a "memory" of previous good english words. 
The objective is to save computation time: in your case, the call to isValidEnglishWord().

Therefore, you need to adapt your alorythm this way:

1. walk through the 'str' string
2. extract a substring from it
3. checkif the substring is a valid word in your memory.

   1. It's in memory: add a space and the word to your result.
   2. It's not in memory: calls isValidEnglishWord and process its return.

It will give something like (not tested nor compiled)

```java
// This is our memory
import java.util.*

private static Map<String, Boolean> memory = new HashMap<String, Boolean>()

public static String buttom_up_split(String str){
   int len = str.length();
   int[] S = new int[len+1];

   String[] result = new String[len+1];  
   for(int i=0; i <= len; i++){
      S[i] = -1;
   }
   S[0] =0;
   for(int i=0; i < len; i++){
      if(S[i] != -1){
         for(int j= i+1; j <= len; j++){
            String sub = str.substring(i, j);
            int k = j;    

            // Order is significant: first look into memory !
            Boolean isInMemory = memory.contains(sub);
            if (isInMemory || isValidEnglishWord(sub)){
                S[k] = 1;
                if(result[i] != null){ 

                    // Memoize the result if needed.
                    if (!isInMemory) {
                        memory.put(sub, true);
                    }

                    result[i+ sub.length()] = result[i] + " " + sub;
                } else {
                    result[i+ sub.length()] = sub;
                }
            }

        }
    }
}
return result[len];
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Personally I always prefer to use memoization as transparently as possible without modifying the algorithm. This is because I want to be able to test the algorithm separately from memoization. Also I am working on a memoization library in which you only have to add @Memoize to methods to which memoization is applicable. But unfortunately this will come too late for you.

The last time I used memoization (without my library) I implemented it using a [proxy class](http://onjava.com/onjava/2003/08/20/memoization.html). An important remark is that this implementation does not support recursion. But this shouldn't be a problem since your algorithm is not recursive.

Some other references are:

- [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memoization)
- [Java implementation](http://www.tek271.com/software/java/memoizer)
- [memoize using proxy class](http://onjava.com/onjava/2003/08/20/memoization.html)

Remark about your algorithm:
How do you handle words that have other words in them? like "verbose" contains "verb", "theory" contains "the" etc...